# Bluetooth programming in C#, connection between mobile device and laptop

Tags: c#, winforms, mobile, bluetooth

I'm writing a programm on my laptop in C#.Net, Windows Forms.
I would like to connect my laptop with mobile phone (NOT Windows phone, but any phone) through the Bluetooth connection.

I was already on many sites, (eg. 32feet.NET) but there are so many files and I'm lost there.
I just need a simple program which is sending data (integer, string ...) to mobile phone and vice versa.

Where do I start? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: Haven't been programing with C# in years, I don't remember back then, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article [My Second Attempt at Blogging - Bluetooth Programming with C#](http://dickchiang.blogspot.com/2008/09/bluetooth-programming-with-c.html)  explains how to use 32feet.NET in easy steps.

below the sample snippet used to send a file to bluetooth device (taken from the same article).

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
Uri u = new Uri("obex-push://" + devAddr.ToString() + "/" + filename);
ObexWebRequest owr = new ObexWebRequest(u);
owr.ReadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
ObexWebResponse response = (ObexWebResponse)owr.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Comment: what is your devAddr?  is this the full address of the file im looking for?